# Colorize plain text string with <span> elements

Tags: javascript, html

Alright, so I made this function:

```
String.prototype.colorize = function() {
    return this.replace(/&([0-9]{1,3})/gi, function($0, $1, offset) {
        return (offset > 0 ? "</span>" : "") + '<span style="color: hsl(' + $1 + ', 100%, 50%)">';
    });
};
```

It basically turns a plain text string into html spans with colors so that, for example &240Hello becomes blue, using the HSL color scale.

Now the problem is, I need it to add `</span>` in the very end of the string only if it has found any matches so that it closes itself. I could store it in str and then do `if (str.indexOf("span") > -1) str += "</span>"`. But I think that looks pretty ugly, is there anyway to fix this right away inside the replacer function?

I have noticed that this doesn't really matter since if you append this using innerHTML it will automagically generate a `</span>` tag, well just for clarity, how do I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To do this robustly I would recommend doing this in three steps. 1 is 'tokenize (split) the string into sections. 2 - decide what colour each section should be. 3 - build up the HTML string by joining them with the appropriate colour tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution, and it's even cleaner than the question's code:

```
String.prototype.colorize = function() {
    return this
        .replace(/&([0-9]{1,3})/g, '</span><span style="color: hsl($1, 100%, 50%)">')
        .replace(/(<\/span>)(.*)/g, "$2$1");
};
```